# Auto set price of upgrades of in game currency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, currency, fibonacci

I am writing a game with in app purchases in that a user receives an in game currency whilst playing which they can then trade for various upgrades.

I want the upgrades to be increasingly hard to acquire but essentially never ending.  It seems that doing this programatically might be a nice way to move forward but am unsure of a good (or well used?) method to use?

So far I have thought of either using a log scale or perhaps the fibonacci sequence i.e.

- Price = 1000 (^ numUpgrades)

or

- 1,2,3,5,8,13,21.... (each upgrade corresponds to the figure at that position within the squenece then multiplied by 1000).  So if a user wanted the 4rd upgrade it would cost 5000

Are these actually suitable methods? What would be the best way to implement the fibonacci sequence method (this seems the most naturally scaling that I can think of)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tool like Grapher and just playing a little bit to get a nice function.

If you want a never ending price then use a [exponatial function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)
If you want a price with ends after let's say 100 purchases, then use [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)
(or [arctan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctan)).